# Trying to replace an element in the Dom document produces an error

Tags: php

I am trying to replace each heading in the html by a div:

```
    $domDocument=new DOMDocument();
    $domDocument->loadHTML($content);
    $heading1=$domDocument->getElementsByTagName("h1");
    
    foreach ($heading1 as $h) {
        $value = $h->nodeValue;

        try {
            $div = $domDocument->createElement("div");
        } catch (DOMException $e) {
            echo $e;
        }
        $div->setAttribute("id",$value);
        $domDocument->replaceChild($h,$div);
    }
```

This causes an error `Fatal error: Uncaught DOMException: Not Found Error in DOMNode->replaceChild(Object(DOMElement), Object(DOMElement)) #1`

Comment: [replaceChild()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php) expects the first argument to be the new element and the second argument to be the old. You got it backwards. If it still doesn't work, try replacing the child from the parent instead, something like this: `$h->parentNode->replaceChild($div, $h);`